# Ruby on Rails String Concatenation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-concatenation

I have a table called Post that has a column called data_string, which is a string set to a default value of "0, ". In my controller for the posts I have an action called add_vote that increments a vote value by 1 and also appends some other string "test" to the data_string. The << operator is not working and I don't know why. When I change the operator to =, it works just fine but that's not what I want to do.

```
def upvote
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @post.vote += 1
  @post.data_string << "as"
  @post.save
  redirect_to action:"index"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 @post.data_string << "as"
```

you could use

```
 @post.data_string =  @post.data_string + "as"
```

Comment: You use old string `@post.data_string` and sum it with `"as"` and then add it to the `@post.data_string` and save it. same as concat

Comment: So, same as `<<`? You know, the one which doesn't work.

Comment: This may be a bug,I have try this in rails 4.1.7 and 4.2.5, it works in 4.2.5, but not in 4.1.7.